# Choosing http status code for unknown command reply

Tags: php, api, http, http-status-codes

So, I'm writing a small test that I have been required to complete and I just want to give it some final touches by adding some header status code responses and some other stuff.

Right now, my dilemma is what HTTP status code to choose for my "Unknown command" response after the `$_GET['cmd']` has been compared to the existing commands list.

```
case 404: $text = 'Not Found'; break;
case 405: $text = 'Method Not Allowed'; break;
case 406: $text = 'Not Acceptable'; break;
```

For which one of the above should I go? And if none, which other?

Comment: "400 Bad Request" is often used for validation errors or wrong parameters

Comment: @arnaud576875 please write an answer with your comment so I can accept it

Answer (score 1):

If you have a url like this:

```
http://example.com/resource?cmd=doesnotexist
```

and the client issues a GET request for it, 404 would be the appropriate HTTP status code because a url with parameters can be considered a unique resource. That resource either exists or does not.